# Error CS0006 when building solution with MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, teamcity

I'm trying to build my solution using MSBuild but I get CS0006 errors:

> CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file
>   'd:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f489de29c28874
>   9e\ProjectB\ExpressionLexer.cs' could not be found [d:\TeamCi
>   ty\buildAgent\work\f489de29c288749e\ProjectB\ProjectB.csproj]   CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file
>   'd:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f489de29c28874
>   9e\ProjectB\ExpressionParser.cs' could not be found
>   [d:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f489de29c288749e\ProjectB\ProjectB.csproj

The problem is that ExpressionParser.cs does not exist in ProjectB, but does in ProjectA referenced by ProjectB. I don't think it's a build order problem because ProjectA builds successfully right before ProjectB...

I'm out of idea...

Comment: Have you checked the `Configuration Manager` in Visual Studio to make sure the `Build` checkbox is checked for each project in each configuration?